# No veo los acentos en un printf en php al ejecutarlo desde cmd Windows en linea de comandos

Tags: php

Al ejecutar el siguiente fichero desde un cmd de Windows no se ven correctamente los caracteres acentuados.

El fichero test.php está grabado como UTF-8.

fichero test.php:

```
<?php
printf ("áéíóúÑñ");
?>
```

> C:\Appserv\php\php -f test.php

Sin embargo si redirecciono la salida a un fichero de la forma

> C:\Appserv\php\php -f test.php > salida

Al abrir el fichero salida si veo los `acentos` y `ñ` correctamente pero en la consola de Windows se ven estos carácteres raros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La versión de Windows es

> Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.17134.165]

La versión de php es

> PHP 5.1.1 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2005 21:39:02)
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2005 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2005 Zend Technologies
>
> with Xdebug v2.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2007, by Derick Rethans

Ya se que la versión de php es antigua pero es que mi cliente no me acepta cambiarla.

La página de codigo activa en el cmd es 850

Si añado chcp 65001 inmediatamente antes de la ejecución de  C:\Appserv\php\php -f test.php ya no se visualiza nada en pantalla.

Comment: puedes por favor añadir como se ven los caracteres cuando no se muestran correctamente?

Comment: Se ve esto en lugar de los acentos ├í├®├¡├│├║├æ├▒

Comment: dependiendo de la versión de windows el default codepage no soporta utf-8. prueba cambiando el encoding del cmd `chcp 1252`, ó `chcp 65001`, para saber el code page actual `chcp` sin parámetros

Comment: si eso no lo soluciona agrega a la pregunta la versión de windows `c:\ver` y php `c:\php -v`

Comment: puedo confirmar que  `├í├®├¡├│├║├æ├▒` es `áéíóúÑñ` en `UTF-8` interpretado como `DOS 850: western european` , ahora  lo raro es que no se vean cuando cambias el chcp, fijate en las propiedades de la ventana del CMD si tiene asignada una fuente truetype (`Consolas` debería ser el default en win10 y soportar caracteres utf-8). por otro lado fijate si en el php.ini no hay una opción `default_charset`  diferente